# Asp.net guaranteed response time

Tags: asp.net, performance, scaling

Does anybody have any hints as to how to approach writing an ASP.net app that needs to have a guaranteed response time?

When under high load that would normally cause us to exceed our desired response time, we want to throw out an appropriate number of requests, so that the rest of the requests can return before the max response time.  Throwing out requests based on exceeding a fixed req/s is not viable, as there are other external factors that will control response time that cause the max rps we can safely support to fiarly drastically drift and fluctuate over time.

Its ok if a few requests take a little too long, but we'd like the great majority of them to meet the required response time window.  We want to "throw out" the minimal or near minimal number of requests so that we can process the rest of the requests in the allotted response time.

It should account for ASP.Net queuing time, ideally the network request time but that is less important.

We'd also love to do adaptive work, like make a db call if we have plenty of time, but do some computations if we're shorter on time.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of Windows Azure? Share your thoughts in the OP, please.

Answer (score 2):

SLAs with a guaranteed response time require a bit of work.

First off you need to spend a lot of time profiling your application.  You want to understand exactly how it behaves under various load scenarios: light, medium, heavy, crushing..  When doing this profiling step it is going to be critical that it's done on the **exact same hardware / software configuration** that production uses.  Results from one set of hardware have no bearing on results from an even slightly different set of hardware.  This isn't just about the servers either; I'm talking routers, switches, cable lengths, hard drives (make/model), everything.  Even BIOS revisions on the machines, RAID controllers and any other device in the loop.

While profiling make sure the types of work loads represent an actual slice of what you are going to see.  Obviously there are certain load mixes which will execute faster than others.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "throw out an appropriate number of requests".  That sounds like you want to drop those requests... which sounds wrong on a number of levels.  Doing this usually kills an SLA as being an "outage".

Next, you are going to have to actively monitor your servers for load.  If load levels get within a certain percentage of your max then you need to add more hardware to increase capacity.

Another thing, monitoring result times internally is only part of it.  You'll need to monitor them from various external locations as well depending on where your clients are.

---

And that's just about your application.  There are other forces at work such as your connection to the Internet.  You will need multiple providers with active failover in case one goes down...  Or, if possible, go with a solid cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the last [mvcConf](http://www.mvcconf.com/videos) one of the speakers compares the performance of various view engines for ASP.NET MVC. I think it was Steven Smith's presentation that did the comparison, but I'm not 100% sure.

You have to keep in mind, however, that ASP.NET will really only play a very minor role in the performance of your app; DB is likely to be your biggest bottle neck.

Hope the video helps.